# Re-rendering specific js file with turbolinks enabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm working with `Rails 4` and would like to use the built in `Turbolink` gem. I'm happy with all it does except I'd like it to reload one of the js files upon every page request.

**In other words I'd like a specific js file to ignore turbolinks, how can I do this?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use 'page:load' event from turbolinks to connect an initialize function to it. It will be called always when turbolinks fully reaload your new page.

```
function initialize() {
  //js code what you want run always
}

$(document).ready(initialize);
$(document).on('page:load', initialize);
```

If you use jQuery a lot, it is useful to install in your Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

and your application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
```

Turbolinks has two other useful events:

```
page:fetch //when new page begin to download
page:change //when the page has changed over
```

Comment: the problem you have to keep in mind here though is that every time it loads, it's loading in addition to the script that was already loaded. So if you're binding events in the script for ex, they will get bound over and over again. Still looking for the best solution to avoid this.

Comment: I think, these problems not exist any more with the latest turbolinks and jquery-turbolinks... You can add always an extra class to your dom element, which could work as a semafor to avoid multiple bounding...

`$(#yourselector:not(.bounded)).addClass('bounded').on('an event', do_this);`

Comment: Correct, just wanted to make people aware. Something that doesn't seem to be mentioned very widely. I wrote a quick script that automatically unbinds any events added before the next page is loaded.