# Rails 4: Morris.js chart doesn't display when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, morris.js

I have a dashboard page that displays a Morris.js chart. The chart displays properly if I manually type the URL or refresh the page, but if I click a link from my application to load the dashboard the chart will not display. It appears this is an issue with turbolinks.

I have found [a strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754227/re-rendering-specific-js-file-with-turbolinks-enabled) that I believe would allow the chart to display on a link click, but I don't know how to implement it as I am not very familiar with Javascript.

**dashboard.html.erb:**

```
...
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa <%= icon_name %> fa-fw"></i> <%= description %> Chart</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= content_tag :div, "", 
            id: 'laser_sheets_chart',
            data: {sheets_stats: result.to_json} %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

**pages.coffee:**

```
jQuery ->
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'laser_sheets_chart',
        data: $('#laser_sheets_chart').data('sheets-stats')
        xkey: 'date',
        ykeys: ['cut', 'programmed'],
        labels: ['Cut', 'Programmed'],
        xLabels: "day"
        pointSize: 3,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true,
        smooth: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that it's a problem with turbolinks. You can disable this on the link to your dashboard page by setting:

> data-no-turbolink='true'

or using the link_to rails helper:

> link_to('Dashboard', data: { no_turbolink: true })