# Disable turbo links for a specific javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a rails application which makes use of turbolinks. I am happy with everything that turbolinks do except that I have a specific javascript file in assets folder which I want turbolinks to ignore.

I have tried adding `data-turbolinks="false"` and it works but I am looking for a way to avoid putting this on every link that requires this.

Removing turbolinks works as well but the rendering of all the pages slowed down quite a bit. 
I have tried the solution on here as well [Re-rendering specific js file with turbolinks enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754227/re-rendering-specific-js-file-with-turbolinks-enabled)
but its not working well and the javascript is really long.

Any advice would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Particularly why you don't like adding `data-turbolinks="false"` to your Javascript files.  If you are combining all of your JS into one  file (which I recommend), then I can understand why.  What version of Rails and Turbolinks are you using?

Comment: Would you be able to post some code to help demonstrate what you are trying to do?